# How to use LinqToExcel to get cell values without header

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an excel like this...

|------------ **Form** ---------------|
|------------------------------------|
| **Name** -------  **Last Name**----|
| Bob     ---------- value -----------|
| **Age**  -----------------------------|
| 30 -------------------------------|
|---------- **Address** -------------|
|------------------------------------|
| **Street** -------  **Postal code**--|
| value     ---------- value ---------|

..and so on, like a register form,
as you can see the value that i need to get, is in the next row(under the title).

How can I do that with LinqToExcel.dll.
And if I had a CheckBox in my sheet, how can i get the selected value (checked or not).

My code (c# .net)

```
var rows = from c in excel.WorksheetNoHeader(sheetName)
           select c;

foreach (var item in rows)
{
   string aux = item[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Ty

Comment: Well, I think here the question is; do you have many records on the same sheet or you only need to retrieve one per sheet?

Comment: Hi, I have about 40 records.

Answer (score 0):

Well for what I understood your excel file should look something like this

[image]

I implemented some code to read this record, but I think it should work for more than only one.
As you can see, I am iterating into the set of rows and avoiding odd rows assuming that they are the  titles.

I hope this works for you!

```
namespace Demo.Stackoverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using LinqToExcel;

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadExcel();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void LoadExcel()
        {
            var directorio = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Book.xls");
            var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(directorio);

            var rows = from c in book.WorksheetNoHeader()
                       select c;
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (people.Count != 0 && people.Last().Age == 0)
                    {
                        people.Last().Age = Convert.ToInt32(row[0].Value.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Person per = new Person()
                        {
                            Name = row[0].Value.ToString(),
                            LastName = row[1].Value.ToString()
                        };
                        people.Add(per);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, ty, but I cant assume that one row its the header and the other the value. Actually, my excel its like a Web Form, the fields are arranged like a table. 
I wish I could attach the excel here =).
Its like: 1st row header one field***
2nd row value 1 field***
3rd row Header for 2 fields***4th row value for the 2 fields***
5th row header*** 6th row value***  7th value 8th row value***
9th row header 1 field  10th row value 1 field ..and so on

Comment: Ok, now I see, can you attach a screenshot as I did, it would be clearer than your table.

Comment: I cant add a img, apparently "no reputation".